# passing props to routes in react-router 2.4

Tags: reactjs

I would like to pass in some props from the router to the components

Something like this:

```
<Route component={Foo} some_prop={12}/>
```

Is there any way to do this with the latest react-router?  I know it was not possible (without using a wrapper) pre 1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're passing them directly to the `<Route />` component like that, it's now possible to do it exactly the way you're suggesting:

```
<Route foo="bar" />
```

Will give you access to the `foo` prop on `this.props.route.foo`

Via: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md#passing-additional-values-into-route-components

As a side note: if you're using something higher level like `<RouterContext />` it is still necessary to use a data wrapper component of some kind, unfortunately.

Comment: I just didn't expect them to be buried inside if the routes prop.  Wonder why they are passed as top level props?

Comment: Routes basically became plain objects behind the scenes when they updated react-router a little while back, so they could behave in a more React-like way. 

There's a little more background on it here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/615#issuecomment-100432086